# launch screen cannot be changed with Delphi 10.4.2 for iOS iPhone APP

Tags: ios, delphi, launch-screen

I am developing an iOS APP by Delphi 10.4.2. The PAserver 12.2.10.3 on BigSur.
I can modify the icons by my own pictures, but the launchscreen picture is always the Delphi torch.
I checked the deploy file list, as shown in the fig. It seems no iPhone launchscreen being added? Not sure where went wrong. wondering if there is any resolution requirement for the launch picture?
Help needed. thanks,

[image]
[image]

Comment: iOS "caches" the launch screen, so any changes won't show until it reloads the cache, which is apparently 24 hours later. Please see [some of the links returned here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+launch+screen+cached). One way to see the changes immediately is to change the CFBundleIdentifier value in the Version Info of the Project Options. If it has $(ModuleName) in the value, changing the name of the project will have the same effect

Comment: thanks. Changing the CFBundleIdentifier won't pass the compile as it encoded in the profile downloaded from Apple. So, have to uninstall the APP, even restart the iPhone, to make it work. hopefully EMBT can have a better solution. I remember to reset sth. related to the deploy file list could resolve this. But cannot recall the exact procedure.  cheers

Comment: "hopefully EMBT can have a better solution". Apple should come up with a solution, since it's them who are causing the problem. As per my first comment, see some of the Google results - it affects *anyone* who develops for iOS